# Redundant edges removed, but no edge table column created

Tags: cytoscape

When removing redundant edges from a network, selecting "Create an edge table column with number of duplicated edges", the duplicate edges are removed, but no edge table column is created. This is a new behavior in 3.8.0. Possibly related is the automatic sequential numbering of edges when importing a network from GML with duplicate edges. Any ideas what is going on? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short (and perhaps not very helpful) answer is that it appears to be a bug.  Can you do a Help->Report a Bug and report it?

Thanks!

-- scooter